# javascript not adding/removing divs in set order

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm working with JavaScript and am having issues with a couple of for loops at a specific value.

When the slider value is incremented, the amount of pics increase by one and vice versa for when its lowered. However, for a reason I'm unsure of, it will remove one of the pics when the slider is incremented from 9 to 10, and will add one when it's lowered from 10 to 9. This problem doesn't occur anywhere else in the slider, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Here's the code. The picture used isn't attached but the missing image favicon does the same job.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var prevnumb = 0;
var num = 2

var numberofdivs = 0;
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  prevnum = num;
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  num = this.value;
  var newnum = num;
  var newprevnum = prevnum;
  console.log(prevnum, num);
  if (prevnum > num) {

    for (newnum; newprevnum > newnum; newnum++) {

      var element = document.getElementById("id");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    }


  } else if (num > prevnum) {

    for (newprevnum; newnum > newprevnum; newprevnum++) {

      var picpol = document.createElement("img");
      picpol.src = "polee.png";
      picpol.setAttribute("id", "id");
      picpol.setAttribute("class", "polio");
      document.getElementById("basecontainer").appendChild(picpol);
      console.log(picpol);

    }

  } else {

    console.log("no change");

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#basecustom {
  text-align: center;
}

.polio {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
Base Customization

<br>
<br>

<div id="basecustom">


  Select your amount of pics
  <input type="range" min="2" max="25" value="2" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>

  <div id="valcont"></div>


  <div id="basecontainer">

    <img class="polioo" src="polee.png" id="id"><img class="polioo" src="polee.png" id="id">

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you indent your code please?

Comment: Thank you for including a Stack Snippet of your problem. Please see [these instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) for doing Stack Snippets. You only include the `body` content in the HTML panel, and you put the JavaScript in the JavaScript panel (not a `script` tag in the HTML panel).

Comment: Side note: Your original question had a `script` tag after `</body>`. Technically, that's invalid (the `html` tag can only have `head` and `body`), it should be just **before** the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing casting value to int. By default it is string. 
`num = parseInt(this.value);`

Above casting will fix your problem.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var prevnumb = 0;
var num = 2

var numberofdivs = 0;
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  prevnum = num;
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  num = parseInt(this.value);
  var newnum = num;
  var newprevnum = prevnum;
  console.log(prevnum, num);
  if (prevnum > num) {

    for (newnum; newprevnum > newnum; newnum++) {

      var element = document.getElementById("id");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    }


  } else if (num > prevnum) {

    for (newprevnum; newnum > newprevnum; newprevnum++) {

      var picpol = document.createElement("img");
      picpol.src = "https://www.vyapin.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/bullet_04-1.gif";
      picpol.setAttribute("id", "id");
      picpol.setAttribute("class", "polio");
      document.getElementById("basecontainer").appendChild(picpol);
      console.log(picpol);

    }

  } else {

    console.log("no change");

  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

#basecustom {
  text-align: center;
}

.polio {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
Base Customization

<br>
<br>

<div id="basecustom">


  Select your amount of pics
  <input type="range" min="2" max="25" value="2" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>

  <div id="valcont"></div>


  <div id="basecontainer">

    <img class="polioo" src="https://www.vyapin.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/bullet_04-1.gif" id="id"/><img class="polioo" src="https://www.vyapin.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/bullet_04-1.gif" id="id"/>

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Please accept the solution if it fixes your problem and help others to find it :)

Answer (score 0):

change `num = this.value;` to `num = parseInt(this.value,10);` in your original code, num will be a string. so when it increments to 10, you will get a string '10'. And prevnum is '9'. And `if (prevnum > num) {` will be true.